# Azure outbound traffic logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, outbound

Are there any logs on a cloud service web role with details of outbound traffic?

I would like to check http requests made to a third party web service in the past.

Quick summary of my situation to provide some context:

- I have a Reserved IP.
- The web site uses HttpClient to POST to the third party web service and
  the Reserved IP is required to be authorized.
- I have been using web roles for about 6 months but yesterday I had a
  problem where all requests to the third party suddenly stop being
  authorized.
- RDP to the server and browsing to http://www.whatismyip.com/ shows
  that the Reserved IP is still being used.
- I had to resolve the issue quickly and restarting the cloud service
  worked; after which requests to the 3rd party are now being
  authorized again.
- The third party insists their service was not experiencing any issues
  but unfortunately they will provide more information to help me
  troubleshot.

Now I'm trying to find what the cause of the issue was.

Any advice on how to troubleshot outbound traffic requests would be much appreciated.

Comment: How you usually troubleshoot outbound requests? It is same in Azure. There is nothing specific to Azure in your request. As if your service was running on your own server, on your own network, what would you do then ?

Comment: I think the problem could be the Authorization header on the request was wrong or that the Reserved IP was not being used when POSTing to the 3rd party. So I could install Fiddler and analyse the traffic as it is going out; did not have time to do this as it is a PROD server and wanted to get it working asap. Also I could configure Tracing to output to a file, but this will help if it happens again.

Comment: My networking knowledge is limited but I reckon it's possible there might be firewall logs, containing details of the outbound traffic when the issue occurred, but I'm not sure if this is correct or how I would go about finding it. Ultimately I'm hoping to find details of the traffic when the issue occurred 2 days ago.

Comment: So if firewall logs are the way to go then I'm not sure where in the Azure infrastructure to find them.